# Do Geophysical Research Letters (AGU) accept PhD thesis as reference?

Tags: publications, citations

Do Geophysical Research Letters (AGU) accept PhD thesis as reference?
In other words, can be possible to cite a PhD thesis in a GRl paper?

On their website they stated that any unpublished studies will not be accepted.

Comment: Usually, PhD theses are published.

Comment: The PhD thesis are published and become public documents. However, please try to make you paper self-consistent, since in general the PhD thesis might be hard to get(unless displayed on public repositories like arxiv).

Comment: I think you misstate the requirements. They do not say that "unpublished studies will not be accepted" as references, only that [all references must be available either online or in print](http://publications.agu.org/author-resource-center/text-requirements/).

Comment: @ff524 in that case, a PhD thesis would be an acceptable source because it has been "published".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. At all universities I've ever heard of, the PhD thesis is public (potentially after a waiting period for intellectual property reasons), and consequently it can be cited.

It may of course be that these theses are not always easy to get -- they may not be on the internet, for example -- but they exist and are available to the public from the library, for example.